# Why the entity class is showing pmd warning "Class is suspected to be a DataClass"

Tags: java, class, pmd

I have a class User as given below

```java
@Entity
public class User {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long primaryKey;
     private String name;
     // some other fields, default constructor, All argument constructor, 
     // getters and setters
```

When I analyzed using PMD code analyzer its showing `the class User suspected to be a DataClass`.

I tried using `UserDataClass` naming for the class but it still shows this warning.

What is the naming convention that we can follow to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 8):

There is no naming convention to make PMD not complain about that.

As long as the [Data Class rule](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_design.html#dataclass) is enabled and your class is not whitelisted, this issue will continue to pop up.

The idea is to avoid Data Classes entirely and instead have classes that provide some *behaviour* (in addition to holding some state). [This SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363916/how-do-i-refactor-a-data-class-to-not-be-one) discusses how one would do that.

That rule as a whole is not universally accepted as useful (there have been multiple requests to remove the rule), so you may just want to disable the rule if it doesn't fit the design philosophy of your project.

Remember: tools like PMD shouldn't be used blindly as sources of some absolute truth. Instead they should be configured to closely match the desired design philosophy and then used to detect unintended deviation from that philosophy.